# Working out co-ordinates of a grid in javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have a grid of 3 x 3 of 50 pixel squares which are numbered 1-9 horizontally, like below;

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

| 4 | 5 | 6 |

| 7 | 8 | 9 |

If I know the number of the square say for instance square 9, and the width of the squares in this instance 50 pixels, how can I programmatically work out the co-ordinate of the square based on a co-ordinate system of 0, 0 starting from the top left.

Square 9 in this case would be `x = 100` and `y = 100`,

I have tried this so far but it fails,

```
x = (squareNumber * squareWidth)
y = (squareNumber * squareHeight)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula is:

```
x = (squareNumber - 1) % numberOfSquaresPerRow * squareWidth
y = (squareNumber - 1) / numberOfSquaresPerCol * squareHeight
```

In your case, since it's a 3 x 3 grid, it would be:

```
x = (squareNumber - 1) % 3 * squareWidth
y = (squareNumber - 1) / 3 * squareHeight
```

In Javascript, which does not use integer division, you have to use the following for `y`:

```
y = Math.floor((squareNumber - 1) / 3) * squareHeight
```

Comment: You'll need to floor the `y` value before you `* squareHeight` since JS doesn't automatically truncate the decimal in integer division. (JS doesn't really have integers.)

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thanks! I did not know about this peculiarity. The answer is now updated.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying all sorts of math and just couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var width=50,height=50;
 function gridPos(n){
      var pos={};
      pos.x=(n -1)%3*width;
      pos.y=Math.floor((n-1)/3)*height;
      return pos;
 }
pos=gridPos(8);
console.log("pos is " + pos.x + " " + pos.y);
```